# Point a link to a certain server

Tags: html

I have a link to a PDF on my website, which has some of its files on one server and some of them on another. How can I point the link to one of the two?
My code looks like this:

```
<a href="/pdf/testing.pdf">Click here</a>
```

Comment: `<a href="http://otherserver/pdf/testing.pdf">Click here</a>`

Comment: what is your question exactly? How to link to externally hosted PDF files?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. Please explain yourself a little better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I posted an answer for you. You need to point the `href` attribute to a specific server using literal URL's.

Answer (score 1):

### Use literal URLs.

For example:

```
<a href="http://server-one.domain.tld/pdf/testing.pdf">Click here</a>
```

Or...

```
<a href="http://server-two.domain.tld/pdf/testing.pdf">Click here</a>
```

You need FQDN's in there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name

Here is an article for you: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/href